# Frazer in WINE?

Tags: wine

Just wondering if anyone successfully ran Frazer in Ubuntu 12.04 with WINE?

Frazer is an inventory management software for auto dealerships, it's extremely outdated, runs off of a server which provides a *.exe link to access it. (Everyone hates it, but it gets the job done.)

If anyone has done this, let me know if it's stable and usable on daily basis without any hiccups.

My ultimate goal is to install Ubuntu on all the systems at our dealership, so far LibreOffice & Gimp have successfully replaced MS Office & Photoshop for everyone here. Last thing I want to test is this Frazer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't tried but there's nothing like trying.

Answer (score 0):

Frazer is not on the [WineHQ repository](http://www.winehq.org/) and from the looks of it it looks like it is rather local (only in the US) so maybe no-one cared for it to run under anything else than Windows.

If it is just an `exe` and not an installer and it does not require registry settings you can try to run it from commandline with

```
wine {path/}{executable}
```

If you are lucky it runs... if not it more than likely to throw some hints and errors or fixme's.

> Alternative

Use virtualbox to install windows and run Frazer from there. You can even use that install to include more windows software you ran into and did not get ported or works not as well.